# Incorrect view of PFUser username in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, parse-platform

{username = ; , email = ;

I am working on a one-to-many relationship blogging app.  I have coded everything to work with my custom TableViewCell including UILabel's nameLabel (to display the author of the blog post), timeLabel (to display the query results for the createdAt date/string), and textContent (to display the actual post that is also a query from a Parse Class object).  Everything works perfectly...except that the nameLabel returns

Obviously this return value is larger than the UILabel that is presented in the custom cell.  Please help me figure this out as all I want to do is query the value of my "author" object which is the pointer to my _User class where the PFUser data is stored on Parse.  Also if I need to explain this more, please ask and I will try my best as I am a new developer.  Thanks!

Wow...if I had 10 reputation I could post a snapshot so everyone would know how to answer me.

```
![ALPostsQueryTableViewController.m file:][2]


#import "ALPostsQueryTableViewController.h"
#import "ALPostsTableViewCell.h"

@interface ALPostsQueryTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ALPostsQueryTableViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Post";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache
    // first to fill the table and then subsequently do a query
    // against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query includeKey:@"author"];

    return query;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (ALPostsTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ALPostsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ALPostsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textView.text = [object objectForKey:@"textContent"];

    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [object objectForKey:@"author"]];
    NSLog(@"Username is %@", [object objectForKey:@"author"]);

    NSDate *created = [object createdAt];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, h:mm a"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:created]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Well I had a screenshot on here...also it comes back <PFUser:(objectIDExample):Null {username = "example" , email ="example"}

Comment: This is nearly the same code I answered about for a different user here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826773/parse-com-tableview-not-loading-objects/24827014#24827014  Are you sharing code or SO users?

Comment: @danh so I'm looking for the findObjectsInBackground method? I understand I need to find the username object but how can I narrow it down to just the "username" object of the "User" parse class. It returns both the username and email fields which gives the (Null) response. I've looked at PFSubclassing, but being new to the iOS dev world, it was a bit overwhelming.  Should I try to subclass the "User" class into a more narrow "Username" class and just call that particular object. If so how can I implement that into the tableViewCell when I'm also calling objects from my "Post" class. Sorry....

Comment: I also thought that it might be getting all the string values from the pointer "author" to my "User" class but then it would also contain password = "example" since that is a string value but it doesn't...

Comment: Do you also control the "Mike J Aspinall" user account?  Or is this some sample code someplace and both you and that user are learning with it?

Comment: I am a different user and this is sample code from populating a pfquerytableviewcontroller. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @danh still getting used to commenting. The above answer is meant for you.

Comment: Gotcha - okay, no worries, sorry for the distraction.  To clarify the question, you are getting data back from parse as you expect but the username is overflowing a text field in the cell and so it's truncated?

Comment: @danh yes, the data is correct however it's filling the UILabel with more than I really want.  Say my username is "whughes511" and I want to return that value in my UILabel...it would return <PFUser:(theObjectID):Null {username = "whughes511" , email = "example@example.com"}  It's not an error...it's just returning that entire phrase into the UILabel.  Like I said, those are string values in my parse "User" class but it's not returning the other string value "password" which doesn't make sense...

Comment: @danh to explain my app... the currentUser creates a post and it saves the post to Parse creating the "author" and "post" object with "author" being the pointer to my "User" class and the "post" obviously containing what the message says.  My TableViewController then queries and loads the data into the tableView where I created a custom cell to display the data in a more user-friendly environment.  Basically I took the sample code and added my code to make a working chat/blogging system with Parse back-end.  I was very proud of it until the UILabel started displaying that enormous value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sounds like is going on is that the object getting returned have relationships that were eagerly fetched using includeKey.

The way to get at their properties is just how you're doing it, but you need to take it one step further and interrogate the internals of the related "author" object (which happens to be a `PFUser`)

```
// replace your code that sets the nameLabel text with this code...
PFUser *author = [object objectForKey:@"author"];
NSString *authorsUsername = author.username;
cell.nameLabel.text = authorsUsername;
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! It worked beautifully. If I had 15 rep I would upvote a million times. Ha now I don't have to throw my computer against anything.